# Op Amp-based CV LM317 power supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, lm317

As many others before, I'm aiming to build my own simple CC CV lab bench PSU based on the LM317 regulator. Now, I've defined most of the circuitry, but I'm stuck with a particular design choice regarding the Adj pin of the LM317.

Since I wanted to use an Op Amp to drive the Adj pin, I wanted to know what are the pros and cons when:

- using the output voltage of the Op Amp at the Adj pin as negative feedback

  vs.
- using the output-voltage regulated by the LM317 as negative feedback.

In my mind the latter would be able to account for the voltage reference fluctuations of the LM317, but I assume that on the other hand it might be somehow unstable. If this is the case, how can I compensate for these instabilities?

Added the schematic for the Adjust-Pin driven LM317 circuit

[image: CC CV LM317 Bench PSU Schematic]

Comment: What is the point of driving the adj. pin with an op-amp?  The whole point of the LM317 is that it is *simple*.

Comment: You should include a **schematic** of what you want to do. The LM317 already has a build-in error amplifier, adding an external one sounds pointless to me but you can maybe convince me otherwise by showing a schematic. Explain **why** the LM317 voltage reference fluctuations are an issue. You investigate stability by doing a **stability analysis**. There are many Lab supply designs to be found, explain **why** you need to design your own. If you intend to design your own then I think that you should be able to answer your questions by yourself.

Comment: you can use an opamp for cc. however, in my experience, the time and effort spent in adapting the lm317 may not be worth it. You may be better off using a TIP122 and designing both the CC and CV. True, there will not be thermal shutdown, so if you really require it, you will have to implement it yourself at the heatsink. If this is your first power supply, use two LM317, the 1st one does CC (with an additional BD139 as variable resistor), and second one does CV.

Comment: I was using the LM317 over forty years ago when it was relatively new. It's not new anymore and it is as inefficient now as it was then. I recommend that you use a modern device and a modern design - unless you are trying to gain first-hand understand of why using the LM317 for a CV+CC PSU is such a bad idea.

Comment: Added Schematic. I'm aware that it's not the most elegant design as well that other people have alredy done similar (better working) circuits, but that was never my point. I'm trying to design my own PSU to learn some of the basic design and working principles. I'm using a LM317 because I have even less experience with discrete BJT o MOSFET linear regulator circuits. I'm using an external Op Amp to add CC CV which could (it isn't right know) digitally driven by an Arduino. The whole intention behind this post is to question one of my design choices, as described in the question above.

Comment: exactly what is the benefit of the lm317 over a TIP122 in your circuit?

Comment: @Indraneel none, if not that I have a LM317 on hand. I see how TIP122 would make my life easier, thank you for pointing me in that direction, i'll very likely consider it for my final design. But I'd still love to understand the pros and cons for certain feedback loop choices as asked in question above.

Comment: @Transistor sorry for bringing up an old question, just wanted to ask; what is the "modern" replacement for lm317/lm338 linear regulators?